# Difference between Binary Semaphore and Mutex in the toilet key example?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex, semaphore

I have read the posts on this topic on Stackoverflow but couldn't understand the gist. Maybe we can limit their difference to a specific example.

There is a toilet with a lock. 
Mutex: One thread takes the key goes in. If any other threads need to enter the toilet they wait. The current owner comes out and gives the key to the the guard(OS kernel), who gives the owner ship of the toilet to another person.

Problem Statement: I see that all the people agree that the shared resource must be unlocked by the same mutex in that thread that locked it. But for a binary semaphore, it can be unlocked in any other thread as well. 
Now please consider the implementation of a semaphore.

First person reaches the toilet, executes the wait statement, and the value of the semaphore structure goes from 1 to 0. Now if any other person(other thread) comes and executes the wait statement, it will block because the 'value = 0'. So why is it always said that any other thread can unlock the toilet/Critical section specially when no other thread can enter the critical section?

Comment: Do you have an example of where it's said that "any other thread can unlock"?  Because as you point it, it sounds indeed illogical.

Comment: Using a semaphore does not guarantee that the thread that gets the semaphore unit has to be the only one that can post it back.

Comment: Martin, can you please clarify how can another thread post(signal) a semaphore given that another former thread has already entered the Critical section and set the value of the semaphore to 0?

Comment: @meaning-matters
Here is the exact sentence
[_A semaphore post (or basically unlock) can be performed by  a different thread. However, in the case of mutex, it should be unlocked only by the same thread_]
[link]http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.592071.6

Comment: Now I get it. There was one subtle point which is that a thread may not necessarily call the wait command, then enter the CS and then post the semaphore.Any thread can arbitrarily post a semaphore( thereby incrementing the value of the semaphore from 0 to 1) without having to wait on the semaphore. However this can violate mutual exclusion and hence more than one thread might be accessing a CS at a time. Thus my understanding is that if a binary semaphore has to do the function of a mutex, then one has to make sure that a post command is always preceded by a wait statement.

Comment: Thanks maite.. this sentence `then one has to make sure that a post command is always preceded by a wait statement` cleared a lot of doubts..

Answer (score 2):

A mutex has thread-affinity.  Only the thread that acquired the mutex can release it.  A semaphore doesn't have affinity.  This is a nice property of mutex, it avoids accidents and can tell you when you got it wrong.  A mutex can also be recursive, allowing the same thread to acquire it more than once.  A countermeasure against accidental deadlock.

Useful properties, you need all the help you can get when writing concurrent code.  But sure, a semaphore can get the job done too.

Comment: That is the standard pthread implementation. There are older (often spin-lock type) implementations that do not have those modern constrains/enhancements. It does not say anywhere in the definition of the word "mutex" that it has to have those properties.

Comment: Sigh, is there ever a way to answer a C question that doesn't require posting a gazillion "but" clauses?  Older than pthread?  It 20 freakin years old.

Comment: @SergeyL., the question is tagged [posix].

Answer (score 0):

A binary semaphore is a regular semaphore that can only have a value of 0 (resource is unavailable) or 1 (resource is available), there is *no* difference between this and a mutex (lock).

After a process enters the toilet the semaphore is decremented and any other people who wait on the semaphore are *blocked* from entering the critical section. The blocked processes/threads/whatever are usually held in a sort of queue ; when the process leaves the toilet the *first* process waiting will be awoken.

I'm not sure where you read that threads can unlock the critical section when the semaphore is 0.

(note, there could be implementation differences)

Comment: It's not always the 'first process waiting' that will get a chance to pee.  This totally on the operating system, and/or the options set for these threads.  A common thing is that the highest priority thread is unblocked to go in.

Comment: And they are usually ordered by that priority, so I am still going to claim *first*

Comment: If thread X gets the semaphore unit, then thread Y sends a unit, thread Z can then arrive and get the unit.  Now both X and Z think they have access rights.

Answer (score -1):

There really is no difference whatsoever between a binary semaphore and a mutex.

The only conceptual difference between those is a mutex can represent only one key, while the semaphore may represent multiple (numbered) keys.

Take this example.

There are 5 toilets:

When you request a semaphore you get a key to a specific toilet.
When you exit that toilet is lined up with the remaining free ones.

If all toilets are full then no one can enter.

If you were to solve this with a mutex then the mutex would be protecting the keybox and you would have to continuously check if a key is available, but a semaphore can represent the keyset.

Comment: There is a large difference.  Any thread can post a unit to a semaphore, not just the one that happened to have acquired the unit earlier.

Comment: @MartinJames In the same way can any thread release a lock on a mutex, doesn't have to be the one that acquired it. All those details are up to the programmer that implements them. It's bad practice, but programmatically not forbidden.

Comment: Yes that is what I cannot really understand. For a binary semaphore, how can any other thread possibly post(signal) without having waited?

Comment: @Umair A lock or semaphore is just a simple number somewhere in memory with some sophisticated logic that makes changes to it atomic and put's threads to sleep if they wish to block on it. Posting to a semaphore is nothing else then atomically incrementing a number and waking up everyone who sleeps on it. There is no mechanic that assigns a lock or semaphore "token" to a specific thread/task. Anyone who knows where the semaphore/mutex resides in memory can post/unlock it.